# Unable to rename a column with Hindi text

Tags: r, dplyr

I am receiving this error after using the rename function built-in dplyr:

```
Error: \uxxxx sequences not supported inside backticks (line 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of tibble 3.1.6 (July 2022), tibbles lack support for most languages besides English, unfortunately. The issue tracking this is [tibble#1014](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/1014) and, unfortunately, the only workaround seems to be not to use Hindi, Greek, and so on when setting tibble column names.